# Remeber the last count of recursive call template within a for -each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XSLT maps that I use for some transformation. My problem is how can I remember the count 1.e; the number of times a loop has run. For example

```
<xsl: for each>  // This runs some 3 times

<xsl: call-template > // This call template recursively runs 10 times
<xsl: with- param >
</xsl: call-template >

<xsl: for each>
```

In the above example outer for loop runs 3 times and inner call-template recurively call itself to print some thing suppose 10 times. So In all I have 3*10 = 30 cycles.

What I need over here is suppose I have an intial number 001, When for loop runs first time it will call template that will recursively call itself 10 times. So  I printed numbers starting from 001 - 010

The next time I run the loop I again printed the numbers from 001-010 ans so on the third time. But What I want is to remember the last count. Suppose in first iteration I reached 010. So in second iteration I will start the count from 011 and print up to 021. 
And in the third time I will print starting from 022-032.

But can any one suggest me how can I do that ? How can I remember the last value up to which the printing is already done?

And one more thing I'm actually limited to XSLT1.0. Thats the reason I have to loop like the example above.

This would be a great help

What I want to do is like this,
Suppose I have an input xml as,

```
<A>

<B from="123456781" to="123456782">
........
</B>
<B from="123456781" to="123456785">
........
</B>
<B from="123456788" to="123456788">
........
</B>

</A>
```

In above xml each node B is associated with a range "from-to".  I need to create as many ouputB node as there is number in given range. and I also have to get unique count of each outputB node that is created. For example output xml can be like ,

```
<root>

<outputB value="123456781" id="001"> // from first B node from="123456781" to="123456782"
<outputB value="123456782" id="002">

<outputB value="123456781" id="003">
<outputB value="123456782" id="004">// from second B node from="123456781" to="123456785"
<outputB value="123456783" id="005">
<outputB value="123456784" id="006">
<outputB value="123456785" id="007">

<outputB value="123456788" id="008">// from third B node from="123456788" to="123456788"

</root>
```

So In above xsl I have recursively populated on the basis of range values in from and to parameter while I have lopped bu for-each on each input B node. Thus creating the exact number of outputB nodes. But the problem here is maintaining unique count or id in generated xml.

Thanks :)

Comment: XSLT is a declarative, compiled language, and as such does not support the cumulative assignment or overwriting of variables, so you could not track this in a global variable as you describe. What precisely are you trying to achieve? Can you post some XML and desired output?

Comment: @Utkanos:- I have updated the post and added Input and output xml to have a better undersatnding what I need to acheive.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is a functional language. You can't "remember" things in a functional language: there is no concept of time, no memory of things in the past. You need to compute everything in the output as a function of something in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't remember values in XSLT or even add up as you go along, except in very specific circumstances. However, in general, you don't need to.

So if you have:

```
<xsl:for-each select="conditiona">  // This runs some 3 times
```

then you have all you need to provide a count:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(conditiona)"/> // this displays 3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the template you just pass in a parameter of the 'depth'.

```
 <xsl:template Name="x">
   <xsl:param name="depth">

   <xsl:call-template name="x">
     <xsl:with param name="depth" select=="depth+1" />
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>
```

Then you do something similar for your outer loop. It is not clear how you are doing this loop, but you may be able to use position(). Then the number you want is position()*10 + depth.

Comment: :- I have updated the post with input and output xmls . That may help u get better understanding of what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

How's this? You can run it at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/Y5b0va) (see output source). It avoids the for-each completely (always best avoided in XSLT).

There's two key concepts here:

1. repeated template matching on the same node for as long as its range requires
2. having nodes kick off the process for their following sibling, rather than having the root-matching template apply to all B nodes. This way, a "where did you get up to?" relationship can be maintained via passed params. It's unorthodox, but works.

**Code:**

```
<!-- root - kick things off, for each B node -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='//B[1]' />
</xsl:template>

<!-- iteration content - B nodes -->
<xsl:template match='B'>

    <!-- recursion params -->
    <xsl:param name='index' select='@from' />
    <xsl:param name='id' select='position()' />
    <xsl:param name='pos' select='position()' />

    <!-- output node -->
    <outputB value='{$index}' id='{$id}' />

    <!-- now recurse for... -->
    <xsl:choose>

        <!-- ...as range requires -->
        <xsl:when test='(@from and @to) and (not($index) or $index &lt; @to)'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='.'>
                <xsl:with-param name='index' select='$index + 1' />
                <xsl:with-param name='id' select='$id + 1' />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>

        <!-- ...next B node, if there is one -->
        <xsl:when test='following-sibling::B'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='following-sibling::B[1]'>
                <xsl:with-param name='id' select='$id + 1' />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

**Outputs:**

```
<outputBs value="123456781" id="1"/>
<outputBs value="123456782" id="2"/>
<outputBs value="123456783" id="3"/>
<outputBs value="123456781" id="4"/>
<outputBs value="123456782" id="5"/>
<outputBs value="123456783" id="6"/>
<outputBs value="123456784" id="7"/>
<outputBs value="123456785" id="8"/>
<outputBs value="123456788" id="9"/>
```